# How to add components inside p-accordionTab header

Tags: angular, angularjs, accordion, primeng

I am kind of struggling with a small situation here. I have a p-acccordionTab like this

```
<p-accordion>
 <p-accordionTab header="Just testing">
   <h5>Nothing here</h5>
 </p-accordionTab>                                                                
</p-accordion>
```

looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y80TH.png)

I want to add some component like p-dropdown or p-inputSwitch in the header part of p-acccordionTab.[For clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJtGK.jpg)

So far, I have tried using p-dropdown with **appendTo** property and also used header like this

```
 <p-accordion>
  <p-accordionTab header="Just testing">
    <header>
      <p-dropdown></p-dropdown>
    </header>
  </p-accordionTab>                                                                
 </p-accordion>
```

But these doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass custom template to p-accordion using header template

```
<p-accordion>
     <p-accordionTab >
          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
           <header>
            <p-dropdown></p-dropdown>
            </header>
           </ng-template>
     </p-accordionTab>                                                                
    </p-accordion>
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-accordion-demo-bu4vde?file=src/app/app.component.html)**